# Fill in around rocks in retaining wall

Tags: landscaping

I have a rock retaining wall that is nothing but problems. Weeds grow in the dirt around the rocks and now we have a varmint (rock chuck, I think) setting up residence. Any suggestions on how to either a) make it so weeds can’t grow around the rocks or b) make it impenetrable so that nothing can sneak in around the rocks. It would be nice if it looked good too...  ;)

One thought I had before the varmint came into the picture was to plant clover or ivy everywhere there is dirt and let it grow.

[image]